# Tizen wearable emulator aeroplane mode on emulator not working. Makes network call even after airplane mode is turned on

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator

My Tizen app makes network calls with CURL. I wanted to test if it fails while no internet connection is available. I disconnected internet but it still attempts to make network call, I guess because it is running connection with some bridge driver. So I turned on aeroplane mode, it showed warning all connections will be disabled. But It does not stop connections and all functionalities work as it would without that mode turning on. Tested wearable emulators with API V5.5 and 4.0 . 
How can I disconnect internet?

Why aeroplane mode on emulator not working?

Answer (score 1):

Airplane mode doesn't disconnect ethernet interfaces.
Emulator connects to the Internet via ethernet (It is also used for sdb connection).
If you want to test in an environment with no internet connection, disconnect network in the Network menu in Control Panel.
Right-click on the emulator and you can find the Control Panel.
I tested with a simple app that uses curl on wearable emulator (Tizen 5.5), and I noticed that the curl operation fails when the network is down.

Comment: emulator still shows it is connected via Ethernet. After link status switch is turned off from control panel.